# What weapons exist for Yuki in The Dishwasher: Vampire Smile

Tags: xbox-live-arcade

I was looking for the various weapons and weapon upgrades for Yuki in The Dishwasher: Vampire Smile. I don't need the locations, just a list. There should only be a small number of weapons and upgrades I think (< 10).

Comment: Best. Name. Ever. (Or at least in recent memory)

Comment: @Raven And unfortunately is yet another name that is longer than our 25 character tag limit. :(

Answer (score 3):

I am [told](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/action/dishwashervampiresmile/show_msgs.php?pid=990607&topic_id=m-1-58804318):

> - Claws (first stage only)
> - Conviction (replaces claws and gotten from the first boss)
> - Machine arm: chainsaw
> - Machine Arm: Chain gun (shotgun attachment gained later on)
> - Painkiller (giant needle)
> - Cloud Sword (behold the power of the clouds)
> - Kamas (Yup no longer belongs to the dishwasher in this game)
>
> The Dishwasher:
>
> - Shift Blade (starts out with it. Missing some combos from the first
>   game)
> - Violence Hammer (Uber strong but slow)
> - Uzi (Gains shotgun later on)
> - Guillotine(Giant Scissors baby)
> - Cleavers (upgradable this time)
> - Squirt gun (This game's version of the arsenal...except it comes with a
>   electric toaster)